# algorithm to assign n jobs to m people n>m

Tags: algorithm

I'm working on project which is Question paper generator, I've few contributors and validators as actors in my system. The contributors contribute questions to my system and validators will validate them, So, is there any particular algorithm which would help me assign questions to the validators evenly and there are no costs related to the questions.

Comment: Will simple round-robin will do? Better solution can involve assignment to validator every time on of the instanse in the validators poll if free

Comment: the validation and contribution phases are different completely, But other than round robin is there any other method? the validation phase follows contribution phase

Comment: Can you estimate (some heuristic function) the cost of the validation for each question?

Comment: there are tags present on each questions ie whether they are easy medium or hard level questions. I guess that could be help with heuristics

Comment: Did my post helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you create the assignment and only then start process them I'm guessing simple round robin will suffice.

If you do have tags on the question then start by sorting them. Second step will be to run till the queue is empty and assign each question to validator at a time.

Here are the algorithm basics:

1. Consider A to bee array of job with size n and B array of people with size m
2. Sort array A such as all the hard question will be at the start.
3. For i in (0, n): assign job A[i] to people B[i mod m].

Following this algorithm will make sure that every people has no more them 1 job more then the other and that at each level of question they are evenly distribute.

If you also can tag the people according their ability to validate the question (I mean person `A[i]` can validate the question faster them `A[j]` them add step of sorting also the people array starting by your fastest person - this will cause that is person `i` has 1 question more then person `j` then it is guarantee that he also be faster in the validation process and their overall time may get equal.

Hope that helps!